# QSS Horizontal TabWidget Styling

Tags: stylesheet, qtstylesheets

So, I'm trying to create a theme for Ninja-IDE. Ninja-IDE uses PyQt, so the themes are made in qss. I'm trying to make my Ninja-IDE look like VS2012. I was just wandering, if it is possible to have separate styles for horizontal and vertical tabs in qss.

```
QTabBar::tab:horizontal
```

isn't working for me.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this answer [QTabWidget tabPosition when using stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340046/qtabwidget-tabposition-when-using-stylesheets)